# Mostrar dialog al usuario cuando se guarde data en firestore (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Junto con saludar, mi consulta es, como se puede notificar al usuario mediante un dialog cuando se haya guardado en este caso un registro en la base de datos firestore.
Actualmente estoy utilizando el desarrollo en capas usando un viwmodel, otra capa de abstracción y una clase para la instancia de firestore.

```
class FirebaseRepo {

    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    fun setUserDataBase(nombre: String, apellido: String, edad: Int, rut: Int, genero: String){

        val user = hashMapOf(
            "nombre" to nombre,
            "apellido" to apellido,
            "edad" to edad,
            "rut" to rut,
            "genero" to genero
        )

        db.collection("usuarios").add(user).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful){
                // Mensaje para el usuario
            } else {
                // Mennsaje para el usuario
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class FirestoreUseCase {

    private val firebaseRepo = FirebaseRepo()

    fun setUserFirestore(nombre: String, apellido: String, edad: Int, rut: Int, genero: String){
        firebaseRepo.setUserDataBase(nombre, apellido, edad, rut, genero)
    }
}
```

```
class FirestoreViewModel : ViewModel() {

   private val firestoreUseCase = FirestoreUseCase()

    fun crearUsuario(nombre: String, apellido: String, edad: Int, rut: Int, genero: String){
        firestoreUseCase.setUserFirestore(nombre, apellido, edad, rut, genero)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando ViewModel, podes hacer un reactivo para atras una vez que el repo avisa que termino de cargar los datos

```
class FirebaseRepo {

private val data = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

fun setUserDataBase(nombre: String, apellido: String, edad: Int, rut: Int, genero: String){

        val user = hashMapOf(
            "nombre" to nombre,
            "apellido" to apellido,
            "edad" to edad,
            "rut" to rut,
            "genero" to genero
        )

        db.collection("usuarios").add(user).addOnCompleteListener {
                isDataPushed(it.isSuccessful)
        }
    }

fun isDataPushed(value:Boolean){
   data.value = value
  }

fun getDataResult():LiveData<Boolean>{
   return data
  }
}
```

Una vez este valor se pushee, volvemos a la UI con el LiveData

```
class FirestoreUseCase {

    private val firebaseRepo = FirebaseRepo()

    fun setUserFirestore(nombre: String, apellido: String, edad: Int, rut: Int, genero: String){
        firebaseRepo.setUserDataBase(nombre, apellido, edad, rut, genero)
    }

  fun getData():LiveData<Boolean>{
   return firebaseRepo.getDataResult()
  }
}
```

Y desde el viewModel observamos el cambio

```
class FirestoreViewModel : ViewModel() {

   private val firestoreUseCase = FirestoreUseCase()

    fun crearUsuario(nombre: String, apellido: String, edad: Int, rut: Int, genero: String){
        firestoreUseCase.setUserFirestore(nombre, apellido, edad, rut, genero)
    }

  fun fetchDataComplition():LiveData<Boolean>{
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    firestoreUseCase.getData().observeForever{
        mutableData.value = it
      }
    return mutableData
   }

}
```

Desde la vista solo esperamos el valor de true para mostrar el dialogo

```
class MainActivity(){

    onCreate(){
       ...
      observeData()
    }

   fun observeData(){
    viewModel.fetchDataComplition().observe(this,Observer{
         if(it) // Mostramos el Dialogo else //No mostramos el dialogo

       })
     }

   }
```

Espero te sirva, lo escribi a mano y puede haber algun typo, para mas info de como hacerlo mejor te dejo un post que hice en medium hace unos dias

https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-exceptions-with-clean-architecture-and-firebase-5efbc13a1d54

Comment: Gracias @Gastón Saillén, justamente estoy estudiando viewModel y el patron MVVM, y tu respuesta es bastante clara, ademas sigo el canal de sociedad androide, el material es excelente me a ayudado bastante.

Comment: Un gusto pablo, cualquier cosa consulta